# What is JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: json, authentication, heroku, netlify

I have an app that works locally but after uploading the db to heroku and the client slide to netlify, I receive the following error when attempting to login.

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
    props.setAuth(true);
    toast.success('Login successful');
  } else {
    props.setAuth(false);
    toast.error(parseRes);
  }
} catch (error) {
  let errorMessage = 'Server error';
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    errorMessage = error.message;
  }
  console.log(errorMessage);
```

Comment: You need to see what data you get before parsing. Most likely it's some sort of error message formatted as HTML, that should give you some idea about the cause.

Comment: But wouldn't I get the same error when running locally if it was that?

Comment: I receive an object with a token.

Comment: @SteveLarsen were you able to solve the issue? if so how did you do it?